# Adding a CDN asset to drupal theme via info file

Tags: theming

Just as the title suggests...I tried using an absolute path:

stylesheets[all][] = 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900'

This doesn't work...how do I add this to a theme?

Comment: On the off-chance you have the fontyourface module installed, you can still use the .info file with something like `fonts[google_fonts_api][] = Archivo Black&subset=latin#regular`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it in the theme template.php file.

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {

      // Load font
      drupal_add_css('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900', array(
        'type' => 'external'
      ));

}
```

Tip: Dont set a protocol to load external resources from Google

Comment: I was afraid of that...I was hoping to keep all the assets in the info file but I guess I'll do it in the template now. :) thanks again.